# Can I sue for being banned from the mall if I didn't do anything wrong?

Tags: united-states

If I'm at a birthday party at a party rental in the mall and uninvited guests show up. They began getting aggressive and shouting. They leave before mall security and police arrive. The police then asks me to leave and I am no longer welcome at the mall because I was involved the the conflict. Neither the mall security nor the rental place asked me to leave and had to be told by 2 police officers and escorted by them and 2 security guards out of the mall. Can I sue and who?

Comment: What makes you think a request to leave constitutes a ban? I.e. it seems a leap from "go" => "do not return".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can a store accuse me of something and ban me without proof?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/18616/can-a-store-accuse-me-of-something-and-ban-me-without-proof)

Answer (score 11):

In general, you can be banned from a private business for any or no reason, **unless** it is because of something not allowed by US law or state law (in the state where the mall is located) such as race, nationality, sexual orientation, etc.